# $\rho_E(x)=\inf_{z\in E} d(x,z)$ prove that $\rho_E(x)=0$ if and only if $x\in \bar{E}$

Tags: real-analysis

Let E be nonempty subset of metric space X, define distance from one point x in X to E by
$$\rho_E(x)=\inf_{z\in E} d(x,z)$$
prove that $\rho_E(x)=0$ if and only if $x\in \bar{E}$.

My proof:
(Forward direction): Suppose $x \notin \bar{E}$, $\bar E$ is closed then $ \bar{E}^c$ is open. $\exists N_{\epsilon}(x) \subset \bar{E}^c$ $d(x,z)\geq \epsilon\gt 0$.

(Backward direction): If $x\in \bar{E}$ there are 2 cases:

Case 1: If $x\in E$ then $\rho_E(x)=0\\$

Case 2: If $x\in E$ then $x$ is a limit point of $E$. For every $ \epsilon \gt 0$, $\exists e \in E$, s.t.$$0\leq \rho_E(x)\le d(x,e) \le \epsilon$$
since $\epsilon$ arbitrary, $\rho_E(x)=0$.

Is my proof reasonable? I'm actually wandering if the inequality in backward direction can get equality here since in some cases, the inequality can't simply get equality:
Consider interval $E=(0,\infty)$, you can't say since for any $\epsilon\gt 0$,$0\leq|x-0|\leq \epsilon$ where x in $E$ so $0$ is in $E$.

Comment: Your proof seems fine. For your last paragraph, one thing to keep in mind is that you've shown $\rho_E(x) = 0$ if and only if $x$ is in the *closure* of $E$, not necessarily in $E$ itself. For the example you gave (i.e. $x=0$ and $E=(0,\infty)$), we do have $\rho_E(x) = 0$, and $x\in\bar{E}$, since $\bar{E} = [0,\infty)$ (assuming we are discussing $E$ as a subset of $\mathbb{R}$).

Answer (score 0):

$\rho(x,E)=0$ iff $inf_{z\in E} d(x,z)=0$ iff there exist a sequence $\{y_n\}\subseteq E$, such that $d(x,y_n)\rightarrow 0$.

$x\in \bar{E}$ iff for any $\epsilon>0$,  we have $B(x,\epsilon)\cap E$ is non-empty iff for every $n\geq1$, there exist $y_n\in B(x,\frac{1}{n})\cap E$ iff there exist a sequence $\{y_n\}\subseteq E$, such that $d(x,y_n)\leq\frac{1}{n}$.

So we have proved your conclusion.